# How to pass item's data to another component, edit data and save data in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, express

I have a book table page to list all the books in the database, mapped with their book ID. If I click the book name, it will link to an edit book page, in this page, the input fields should be filled with the book detail, I can edit the book detail and save it in the database.

The problem is, how do I pass the book detail to another component?

Book table component

```
class BookTable extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            books: [],
            book: {}
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='display-container'>
                <div className="card-group-admin">
                    <div className="container">
                    <div className="row row-cols-3">
                    {this.state.books.map(book => 
                        <div className="card" style={{height:550 + 'px', width:320 + 'px'}} key={book._id}>
                        <img src={`http://localhost:3001/${book.bookImage}`} className="card-img-top" alt="comic book coverpage" />
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <Link to={`/books/${book._id}`} book={this.setState={book}}><h5 className="card-title">{book.bookName}</h5></Link>
                                <p className="card-text">{book.bookDescription}</p>
                                <div className="card-bottom-container">
                                <p className="card-status">{book.bookStatus}</p>
                                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleDeleteClick(book._id)} 
                                className="btn btn-secondary" id="btnLength">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>)
                    }</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am not sure whether "book={this.setState={book}}" inside the  tag is correct or not, that's probably is where the problem at.

Edit component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {book} from './BookTable';

function Edit ({book}) {

    const [bookName, setBookName] = useState(book.bookName);
        const [author, setAuthor] = useState(book.author);
        const [publisher, setPublisher] = useState(book.publisher);
        const [yearReleased, setYearReleased] = useState(book.yearReleased);
        const [type, setType] = useState(book.type);
        const [advancedBookType, setAdvancedBookType] = useState(book.advancedBookType);
        const [rentalPrice, setRentalPrice] = useState(book.rentalPrice);
        const [bookDescription, setBookDescription] = useState(book.bookDescription);


    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const bookDetail = {
            bookName,
            author,
            publisher,
            yearReleased,
            type,
            advancedBookType,
            rentalPrice,
            bookDescription };

        axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/app/books/${_id}`, bookDetail)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        
    }

    const history = useHistory();

    const handleBack = () => {
        history.push("/adminDashboard");
    }

    return (
        <div className="editPage">
            <h1>Edit book page</h1> 
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    
                    <label className="editLabel">Book name:</label>
                    <input type = 'text' 
                    value={book.bookName} 
                    onChange={(e) => setBookName(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" />
    
                    <label  className="editLabel">Author:</label>
                    <input type = 'text'
                    value={book.author} 
                    onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" />
    
                    <label  className="editLabel">Publisher:</label>
                    <input type = 'text'
                    value={book.publisher} 
                    onChange={(e) => setPublisher(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" />
    
                    <label  className="editLabel">Year released:</label>
                    <input type = 'number'
                    value={book.yearReleased} 
                    onChange={(e) => setYearReleased(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" />
    
                    <label  className="editLabel">Type:</label>
                    <select type = 'text'
                    value={book.type}
                    onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                    <option>Comedy</option>
                    <option>Love</option>
                    <option>Horror</option>
                    <option>Detecting</option>
                    <option>Fiction</option>
                    <option>Adventure</option>
                    <option>Action</option>
                    <option>Youth</option>
                    </select>
    
                    <label className="editLabel">Advanced book type:</label>
                    <select type = 'text'
                    value={book.advancedBookType}
                    onChange={(e) => setAdvancedBookType(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                    <option >None</option>   
                    <option>Popular</option>
                    <option>New release</option>
                    </select>
    
                    <label className="editLabel">Rental price ($):</label>
                    <input type = 'number'
                    value={book.rentalPrice} 
                    onChange={(e) => setRentalPrice(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group form-control-sm input" />
    
                    <label className="editLabel">Book description:</label>
                    <textarea value={book.bookDescription}
                    onChange={(e) => setBookDescription(e.target.value)}
                    className="form-control form-group textbox" rows="4">
                    </textarea>
    
                    <div className="buttonGroup">
                    <button onClick={() => handleBack()} className="btn btn-outline-dark">Back</button>
                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="right" value="Save" />
                    {/* <input type="reset" className="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="right" value="Delete" /> */}
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    );
}



export default Edit;
```

Backend book route

```
router.put('/books/:id', (request, response) => {
    Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: request.params.id }, request.body, { new:true, useFindAndModify: false },
         (err, book) => {
        if (err) {
            response.send(err);
        }
        response.json(book);
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/books/${book._id}`, state: { data: book } }}> {book.bookName} </Link>
```

in Edit component

const { data } = props.location.state;